# Использовать ли SSL для передачи пароля в некоммерческом сайте?

Tags: веб-программирование

Хостинг за установку SSL слишком много просит.  Достаточно ли просто POST запрос делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обойтись и без SSL. На работе сайта это никак не скажется. SSL нужен для шифрования данных между пользователем и сайтом. Если 3-я сторона (провайдер) просматривает трафик, при использовании SSL он не увидит передаваемые данные от пользователя на ваш сайт. Стоимость услуги SSL складывается из стоимости выделенного вам IP + заказа самого сертификата + какого-то интереса вашего хостера.

Comment: Насколько сильно защищена передача учетных данных в POST-запросе?

Comment: @Alex9, в обычном POST запросе совсем не защищена. Это всего лишь один из способов передать данные от пользователя до сервера. Вы можете подключить SSL сертификат позже, на работу сайта это никак не повлияет.